# How can I combine 93 reps into 3 groups according to value?

Tags: r

I have a 24 data sets of 93 observations each. There are only two variables, a factor (size) and it's response (percent). The factor value ranges from 0-2000. I would like to combine these observations into three groups based on factor values (0-2, 2-50, and 50-2000) and see the total combined response value for each. I have tried using the `group_by` and `summarize` functions, but I am fairly new with r and I am in over my head.

In addition, is it possible to automate this so that one string of code can do this for all 24 of my data sets? They are saved as different text files in the same folder. I don't know the limitations of r, so this might not be possible. If necessary, one code that I could run 24 times would still get the job done.

Here's an example of one of the data sets -

```
>dput(head(data))
   structure(list(run.size.percent = structure(c(2L, 13L, 24L, 35L, 
46L, 57L), .Label = c(",2000,", "1,0.375,0.013", "10,0.868,0.11", 
"11,0.953,0.12", "12,1.047,0.12", "13,1.149,0.13", "14,1.261,0.14", 
"15,1.385,0.14", "16,1.520,0.15", "17,1.668,0.15", "18,1.832,0.16", 
"19,2.011,0.17", "2,0.412,0.023", "20,2.207,0.17", "21,2.423,0.18", 
"22,2.660,0.19", "23,2.920,0.20", "24,3.205,0.21", "25,3.519,0.22", 
"26,3.863,0.24", "27,4.240,0.25", "28,4.655,0.26", "29,5.110,0.28", 
"3,0.452,0.034", "30,5.610,0.30", "31,6.158,0.31", "32,6.760,0.33", 
"33,7.421,0.35", "34,8.147,0.37", "35,8.943,0.39", "36,9.817,0.42", 
"37,10.78,0.45", "38,11.83,0.47", "39,12.99,0.50", "4,0.496,0.049", 
"40,14.26,0.53", "41,15.65,0.56", "42,17.18,0.58", "43,18.86,0.59", 
"44,20.70,0.59", "45,22.73,0.58", "46,24.95,0.55", "47,27.39,0.52", 
"48,30.07,0.49", "49,33.01,0.46", "5,0.545,0.061", "50,36.24,0.45", 
"51,39.78,0.45", "52,43.67,0.45", "53,47.94,0.44", "54,52.62,0.42", 
"55,57.77,0.38", "56,63.41,0.35", "57,69.61,0.32", "58,76.42,0.31", 
"59,83.89,0.33", "6,0.598,0.072", "60,92.09,0.36", "61,101.1,0.42", 
"62,111.0,0.49", "63,121.8,0.59", "64,133.7,0.74", "65,146.8,0.94", 
"66,161.2,1.19", "67,176.9,1.49", "68,194.2,1.82", "69,213.2,2.18", 
"7,0.656,0.083", "70,234.1,2.55", "71,256.9,2.94", "72,282.1,3.34", 
"73,309.6,3.78", "74,339.9,4.25", "75,373.1,4.73", "76,409.6,5.20", 
"77,449.7,5.60", "78,493.6,5.87", "79,541.9,5.93", "8,0.721,0.093", 
"80,594.9,5.77", "81,653.0,5.37", "82,716.8,4.77", "83,786.9,4.03", 
"84,863.9,3.21", "85,948.3,2.36", "86,1041,1.55", "87,1143,0.81", 
"88,1255,0.30", "89,1377,0.056", "9,0.791,0.10", "90,1512,0.0044", 
"91,1660,0", "92,1822,0"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks very much for any help! Please let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

## 1) Summary Table

You were on the right track with the group_by/summarise idea! There are just a few steps to do first.

```
# load tidyverse packages
library(tidyverse)

# load dataset
# (I did this differently than you did in the question - I'm not familiar with the structure function)
data <- tibble(x= c("0,2000,0", "1,0.375,0.013", "10,0.868,0.11",
                  "11,0.953,0.12", "12,1.047,0.12", "13,1.149,0.13", "14,1.261,0.14", 
                  "15,1.385,0.14", "16,1.520,0.15", "17,1.668,0.15", "18,1.832,0.16", 
                  "19,2.011,0.17", "2,0.412,0.023", "20,2.207,0.17", "21,2.423,0.18", 
                  "22,2.660,0.19", "23,2.920,0.20", "24,3.205,0.21", "25,3.519,0.22", 
                  "26,3.863,0.24", "27,4.240,0.25", "28,4.655,0.26", "29,5.110,0.28", 
                  "3,0.452,0.034", "30,5.610,0.30", "31,6.158,0.31", "32,6.760,0.33", 
                  "33,7.421,0.35", "34,8.147,0.37", "35,8.943,0.39", "36,9.817,0.42", 
                  "37,10.78,0.45", "38,11.83,0.47", "39,12.99,0.50", "4,0.496,0.049", 
                  "40,14.26,0.53", "41,15.65,0.56", "42,17.18,0.58", "43,18.86,0.59", 
                  "44,20.70,0.59", "45,22.73,0.58", "46,24.95,0.55", "47,27.39,0.52", 
                  "48,30.07,0.49", "49,33.01,0.46", "5,0.545,0.061", "50,36.24,0.45", 
                  "51,39.78,0.45", "52,43.67,0.45", "53,47.94,0.44", "54,52.62,0.42", 
                  "55,57.77,0.38", "56,63.41,0.35", "57,69.61,0.32", "58,76.42,0.31", 
                  "59,83.89,0.33", "6,0.598,0.072", "60,92.09,0.36", "61,101.1,0.42", 
                  "62,111.0,0.49", "63,121.8,0.59", "64,133.7,0.74", "65,146.8,0.94", 
                  "66,161.2,1.19", "67,176.9,1.49", "68,194.2,1.82", "69,213.2,2.18", 
                  "7,0.656,0.083", "70,234.1,2.55", "71,256.9,2.94", "72,282.1,3.34", 
                  "73,309.6,3.78", "74,339.9,4.25", "75,373.1,4.73", "76,409.6,5.20", 
                  "77,449.7,5.60", "78,493.6,5.87", "79,541.9,5.93", "8,0.721,0.093", 
                  "80,594.9,5.77", "81,653.0,5.37", "82,716.8,4.77", "83,786.9,4.03", 
                  "84,863.9,3.21", "85,948.3,2.36", "86,1041,1.55", "87,1143,0.81", 
                  "88,1255,0.30", "89,1377,0.056", "9,0.791,0.10", "90,1512,0.0044", 
                  "91,1660,0", "92,1822,0")) %>%
  # separate into three fields
  separate(x,
           into = c("run", "size", "percent"),
           sep = ",") %>%
  # only keep useful fields - size and percent
  select(size, percent) %>%
  # change field types to numeric
  mutate_all(as.numeric)

# group by size: categories [0,2), [2,5), [5,2000]
data_summary <- data %>%
  mutate(size_bin = cut(size,
                        breaks = c(0,2,5,2000),
                        include.lowest = TRUE,
                        right = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(size_bin) %>%
  summarise(percent_sum = sum(percent))

# take a look at the result
data_summary
```

## 2) Repeat process over several files

Yes, you can definitely set this up to run over many files in a folder!

Do you want all of the files to feed into one dataset? If so, here's the code you'd use:

```
data_all <- list.files("folder_name/") %>%
  map_df(~read_csv(path = paste0("folder_name/", .)) %>%
           # only keep useful fields - size and percent
             select(size, percent) %>%
             # change field types to numeric
             mutate_all(as.numeric)  %>%
           
           # group by size: categories [0,2), [2,5), [5,2000]
           mutate(size_bin = cut(size,
                                    breaks = c(0,2,5,2000),
                                    include.lowest = TRUE,
                                    right = FALSE)) %>%
           group_by(size_bin) %>%
           summarise(percent_sum = sum(percent))
  )
```

If you want to keep the datasets separate, the code would be different. (I'm not sure how to code that right now, but I'll look into it if that something you're interested in!)

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer! I'm not at my desk right now but I'm excited to try it out. Yes, the original dataset is a little strange because of the way the older machine and program I used creates it. And yes, I would like to keep the datasets separate, although I appreciate sharing the code you gave! I plan on analyzing each dataset on it's own. Thanks again!